# FileMaker: How to auto-fill field in a new record with value from different field in previous record

Tags: filemaker

FileMaker Pro Version 11.  Two fields of interest in a record:  Let's call them start_value and end_value.

When creating a new record I want start_value to be auto-filled with end_value from the previous record (which should be the highest end_value in the table).

I am an old-time C coder, this is my first FileMaker attempt, so be gentle with me.  :-)

Comment: Why would you need to duplicate the data so?

Comment: The start_value of the new record needs to be the end_value of the previous record.  This is not duplicating data, this is auto-filling a field on the new record with data from a different field in a previous record,

Comment: The value is already recorded in the previous record. Copying it to the next record **is** duplicating it. Sometimes it is necessary (e.g. for performance reasons) but most of the times it only creates problems (esp. when data is edited).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cartesian self-relationship and add Auto-Enter calculation to the start_value field definition to be Max(end_value). Max(end_value) have to refer to the related field and not the local one.

===

Added some instructions:

Open Define Database and select the Table Occurrence of the table where fields start_value and end_value are. You can also add another table occurrence of this table for the calculation. Let's call it MyTable.

Duplicate MyTable and give it a name, e.g. MyTable_self

Create a relationship MyTable to MyTable_self, by any field will be fine, but preferably by Primary Key.

Open "Edit Relationship" and change the relationship type from join (=) to cartesian ( x ).

Open the filed definition for start_value in MyTable.

Change Auto-Enter options to "Calculated Value" and add formula

```
Max(MyTable_self::end_value)
```

The context of calculations has to be "MyTable"

Comment: Looks like this is on the path that I want to take.  However, I'm new to FileMaker.  Can you give me more detail on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

My last answer was insane . I worked through your problem and found a working solution.

1. Create a new field maxvalue(Field type = summary ).
2. .A prompt shows you to find maximum value via checkbox Maximum then Select end_value field
3. Goto start_value field->field options->auto-enter
4. Check Calculated value
5. click specify and write 'maxvalue' without quotes

Comment: The problem with a summary field approach is that it works on a found set. If the last record is omitted the new record will have incorrect value set in start_value

Comment: @NicolaiKant Thanks for pointing this out. BDW I did not assume things I just provided him with the working solution.

Comment: Well, it will not be a working solution if you do not have a full found set. I did not criticise your reply, I just pointed out a potential issue.